# Array with many values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have a table (see image below) that includes the polish and latin names for a selection of different herbs.

I'd like to obtain a `$herbs[]` array, that contains an array for each row, e.g.:

```
$herbs = [[mieta pieprzowa, mentha piperita],[kozlek lekarski, valeriana medicinalis]...]
```

The code for receiving `latin_name` looks like this, so what should I change?

```
<?php
$connection = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","password","herbarium");
if ($connection→connect_error) die("Fatal Error");
$herb = $_GET['q'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM herbs WHERE (latin_name LIKE '%$herb%') OR (polish_name LIKE '%$herb%')";
$result = $connection→query($query);
$data = array();
while ($row=$result→fetch_assoc()){
$data[] = $row['latin_name'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

[image: my table]

Comment: What the error? Also, think about SQL Injection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837400/sql-injection-mysql

Comment: You want to get the entire row? so why don't you just remove `['latin_name']` from this line: `$data[] = $row['latin_name'];` ?

Comment: Instead of latin_name I'd like to get also polish_name so it would as in example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [mysqli_fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) + a small change of your SQL Query.

In example below I changed your query to fetch only two columns (latin and polish name) and instead of using `while()` loop you can fetch all records at once (until you don't need to process this data).

```
$connection = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","password","herbarium");
if ($connection→connect_error) die("Fatal Error");
$herb = $_GET['q'];
$query = "SELECT latin_name, polish_name FROM herbs WHERE (latin_name LIKE '%$herb%') OR (polish_name LIKE '%$herb%')";
$result = $connection→query($query);
$data = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
echo json_encode($data);
```

It should return you an array with `key=>value` result like:

```
[
  [
    'latin_name' => 'Abc',
    'polish_name' => 'Abc_PL'
  ],
  // ...
]
```

Which might be a bit better idea instead of returning only values.

Comment: Thanks :> Much greater and understandable for me!

Comment: @farmaceut Powodzenia! ;)

Comment: Dzięki, dzięki ;) Pojawię się tu nie raz jeszcze

Comment: To może jeszcze w ramach tego dopytam sie... Jakkolwiek zwraca mi też wartość z polish_name, to niestety nie ma ogonków, a baza danych jest w utf-8... co poradzic na to?

Comment: Sprawdz http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.set-charset.php i czy plik .php ma kodowanie utf8